# Getting error when panning "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'font' of null" in chartjs-pluggin-zoom

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I am getting error in console
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'font' of null" while i am panning in any direction(x/y).

Also my x-axis labels also get disloacted when i pan(i think this is because of error).

i want zoom and pan as smooth as in this [link](https://codepen.io/marcusvilete/pen/EEpKMx?editors=1010)-

```
pan: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: "xy",
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true,
      drag: false,
      mode: "xy",
 }
```

i have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-wb5dhl) of my code.